# Apply editbin in cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to automatically call `editbin` with some options from within a `cmake` script after the executable has been build. So far without any luck.

- is there any example for using `editbin` in `cmake`?
- is there an example for using any executable in `cmake` after an executable has been build?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events `add_custom_command(TARGET target_name POST_BUILD COMMAND "${editbin_exe} $<TARGET_FILE:target_name>")`

Comment: add_custom_command can be executed on build events. Use generator expression `$<TARGET_FILE:...>` to access the path to the output file. You have to find `editbin` prior to calling the command

Comment: Thanks for the hints, looks like to start to work a bit, though I think I still have some problems with the option `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,6.00 /OSVERSION:5.1` as they are translated to `\SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,6.00 \OSVERSION:5.1`. Any suggestions?

Comment: "I still have some problems with the options... " - Probably, you specify these options wrongly. Please, update your question post with the **exact code** where you specify these options.

Comment: I think I just found the solution, I should use the `VERBATIM` option as well, I'm still doing some tests, in case of problems I certainly will update the question.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik please add an answer, so I can accept it (and maybe also include a few words about `VERBATIM` and the meaning of `$<TARGET_FILE:target_name>` in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) for build events, that is, it will be executed each time you build your target.

**From the docs:**
A POST_BUILD event may be used to post-process a binary after linking. For example, the code:

```
add_executable(myExe myExe.c)
add_custom_command(
  TARGET myExe POST_BUILD
  COMMAND someHasher -i "$<TARGET_FILE:myExe>"
                     -o "$<TARGET_FILE:myExe>.hash"
  VERBATIM)
```

will run someHasher to produce a .hash file next to the executable after linking.

As for `VERBATIM`:

> All arguments to the commands will be escaped properly for the build tool so that the invoked command receives each argument unchanged. Note that one level of escapes is still used by the CMake language processor before add_custom_command even sees the arguments. Use of VERBATIM is recommended as it enables correct behavior. When VERBATIM is not given the behavior is platform specific because there is no protection of tool-specific special characters.

---

So in your case you first need to find an executble for `editbin` and then add your command:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET target_name POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND "${editbin_exe} $<TARGET_FILE:target_name>")
```

Where `$<TARGET_FILE:target_name>` is a [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#target-dependent-queries) which yields a path to the output binary file of target `target_name`.